# Битрикс Задать условие в $arFilter на количество элементов во множественном свойстве

Tags: php, битрикс

У элемента айблока есть множественное свойство. Нужно при GetList задать $arFilter с таким условием, что берем элементы у которых записей во множественном свойстве меньше 10

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, Ваш запрос GetList и $arFilter который Вы пишите

Comment: В том то и проблема, что мой GetList и $arFilter вам ни о чём не скажет, так как там нет этого функционала.
```
$query2 = CIBlockElement::GetProperty(ORDERS, (int)$ob->fields['ID'], [], array("CODE" => "CONTRACTORS"));
            while ($contractorsUserId2 = $query2->GetNext()) {
                $contractors_value[] = $contractorsUserId2['VALUE'];
            }
```
пришлось перебирать свойства самого элемента. А нужно это в фильтре сделать

Comment: Давно с Битриксом не работал, поэтому такие тонкости не припомню :) Однако в данной ситуации просто добавил бы новое свойство инфоблоку, в которое при обновлении элементов вносил бы кол-во записей.